# PHP - upload a pdf file with separating each page to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I have tried to upload a whole pdf file to mysql database, but I have an idea to upload a whole file with splitting each page. For example, uploading a booklet.pdf with 5 pages, I would like to split 5 page into booklet-1.pdf, booklet-2.pdf... via PHP, is it possible to do that?

Comment: What's the underlying operating system? You can probably write something in PHP but it's better to use tools that are already available.

Comment: I've never done this before, but Googling "php pdf split" turns up quite a few options. Have you tried any of them?